# Rasp Pi 3 won't boot any more with Things 1.0

Tags: raspberry-pi3, boot, android-things

I have a Rasp pi 3B. I installed Things 0.7 on it and developed an app. All was good.

I installed Things 1.0 and my app, and it ran fine for a week or two, and now the pi won't boot. I'm stuck on the rainbow screen. The red led is on, and the green flashes for a moment on powering up.

There was a thunderstorm which made the power supply flicker. I thought maybe this had caused some damage. I've tried reinstalling Things. No change. I tried installing Raspian, and the pi booted up just fine, so I'm thinking both the card and the pi are actually good. When I put Things 1.0 back on the card, it doesn't boot again.

Any clues?

Comment: Try to reinstall Android Things.

Comment: I've reinstalled Android things several times. I just get the four pixels on the display, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

My app is designed to control an irrigation system. So the GPIO pins are connected to relays which operate some valves.

I tried disconnecting all the pins and rebooting, and it now works. So it was something to do with the pins being wired up. I don't know why the connections would make a difference as there is no voltage on any of the wires. I'll look into it further, but I really don't want to have to disconnect and reconnect all the wires every time I reboot (there are 16 relays). If anyone can suggest why I am seeing this behaviour I'd be grateful.